# Timezone in orcal-adf application

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i trying to make attendance program based on orcal DB and adf web application.
i need to obtin the server time in my DB table when the user log in or i need to know the expression builder for login button. thank you

Comment: And what've you tried already? Show us some code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a View Object based on sql expression:

```
select SYSDATE as db_date from dual
```

Make sure you expose this view object through one of your application modules, then expose DbDate attribute in your page.